# A python method without self as the first parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have seen that this question has been asked multiple times and will be marked a duplicate. Yet, I see no proper answer.

I understand that when using OOPS concept, the instance of the object is sent as the first parameter. However, while solving a few algorithms, I see a few methods defined without `self` and this confuses me.

Can someone please explain what is happening here and not why `self` is being used?

```py
class Solution:
        def __init__(self):
            self.ans=0

        def countUnivalSubtrees(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
            if not root:
                return 0


            def chk(node):
                if node is None:
                    return -1
                if node.left is None and node.right is None:
                    self.ans+=1
                    return True
                l=chk(node.left)
                r=chk(node.right)
                if node.left and node.right:
                    if node.left.val==node.right.val and l and r and node.val==node.left.val:
                        self.ans+=1
                        return True
                if l==-1 and r and node.val==node.right.val:
                    self.ans+=1
                    return True
                if r==-1 and l and node.val==node.left.val:
                    self.ans+=1
                    return True
                return False

            self.ans=0
            chk(root)        
            return self.ans
```

The method I am referring to here is `chk(node)`.

Comment: `chk` isn't a method.

Comment: @user2357112: Can you please throw some more light on it? So, does it mean you can define a function inside a class and use it? I have never used it this way.

Comment: `chk` is a function inside a `method` of the class. A method is normally called by `obj.method()`, where the `obj` is the instance of the class, which gets passed via `self` to the method. If you notice how `chk` is called, you will see it is not called on any object, it just has one parameter node and it can operate independently.

Comment: `chk` is a function defined inside `countUnivalSubtrees`. You can do that. Python function definitions are ordinary statements like any other; they can appear anywhere you could put any other kind of statement.

Comment: @user2357112, Sayandip Dutta: Don't have the ability to upvote yet. Thanks a ton :-)

Comment: the term to search for "scoping", specifically "lexical scoping".  see [here](https://medium.com/@dannymcwaves/a-python-tutorial-to-understanding-scopes-and-closures-c6a3d3ba0937) for an intro.  specifically `self` is bound by an enclosing scope, so the variable is available inside `chk`

Comment: @SayandipDutta / user2357112-supports-monica: Getting back on this, how different is it from a static method? Do you think there would be any difference performance-wise or otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

chk is just function inside method:
you can rewrite your class like that:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ans=0

    def countUnivalSubtrees(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        if not root:
            return 0
        self.ans = 0
        self.chk(root)        
        return self.ans

    def chk(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return -1
        if node.left is None and node.right is None:
            self.ans += 1
            return True
        l = self.chk(node.left)
        r = self.chk(node.right)
        if node.left and node.right:
            if node.left.val == node.right.val and l and r and node.val == node.left.val:
                self.ans += 1
                return True
        if l == -1 and r and node.val == node.right.val:
            self.ans += 1
            return True
        if r == -1 and l and node.val == node.left.val:
            self.ans += 1
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: I think this would do something different.  the `self` in the OPs version would always refer to the same object, while this version changes it every time you recurse into a node

Comment: oops, I misread what object this was being defined/called on.  somehow I read it as each `node` having an `ans`, rather than the `Solution`s, which would have led to lots of partial subtotals